# Why does the C# extension for VS Code insert nothing and remove what I typed when accepting a suggestion for an override?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

VS code shows me override suggestions, but when I try to use them by pressing Enter or tab, it just deletes the whole thing and leaves only the first letter:

[image: Example: When I try to accept the suggestion, it just deletes it.]

I am working on a Unity project so maybe that might have something to do with it. This problem is not only with this specific class, but with a whole project. I have no idea what else to provide, as I'm new to intelisense and stuff I'm sorry if this is not enough info in the question... At least help me find the direction to go I'm lost.

#### Versions:

VS Code "C#" Extension version: v2.0.413 
VS Code "C# Dev Kit" Extension version: v0.3.21

#### This class:

```cs
public class PlayerMovementState : PlayerState
    {
        public PlayerMovementState(IStateMachine stateMachine, PlayerEntity player) : base(stateMachine, player)
        {
        }
    }
```

#### Base class:

```cs
public abstract class PlayerState : BaseStateMachineState
    {
        //...

        #region Drawing

        //...

        #endregion
        #region Main Methods

        public virtual void Move() 
        {
            player.Rigidbody.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        }

        #endregion
        #region Callback Methods

        //...

        #endregion
        #region Damage

        //...

        #endregion
        #region Helper Methods

        //...

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: I once created an issue at the VSC repo about that VSC deletes stuff at autocomplete that is after a space, nothing done because: they could not reproduce, other users could.

Comment: welcome to visual studio code! :P  You havent mentioned how you setup code to do unity, there are a few ways, and most of them seem to break easily.   Unity itself doesnt claim to work with the c# dev kit, However it was not long back that after seeing far too many posts with issues I followed the instructions on the vs code website and had zero issues.  I just cant say i overly enjoyed the experience :D

Comment: I set up unity by downloading their extension and it just kinda started working for me. I also had to download .NET Framework and an SDK, but I haven't tinkered with those. Just downloaded them.

Comment: ok but you also from your own text got the new ms dev kit so thats not all what you did, did you follow the vs code how to work with unity instructions?

Comment: 1) would you mind re-recording your gif in screencast mode and with higher resolution? Use `Developer: Toggle Screencast Mode` in the command palette. 2) does this happen for all programming languages? Try a couple of other ones please.

Comment: does this happen for languages other than C#? Does this happen for C# if you disable all non-C# extensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is an instance of this bug: [Override completion broken #6011](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6011), which is apparently fixed by this Pull Request: [Fix completionComplexEdit: Use fsPath instead of path #6315](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/pull/6315), which will be released soon ([source](https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6011#issuecomment-1719976784)) probably in some version slightly greater than v2.2.10.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gathered, it seems to be just a bug with autocompletion of overrides, so the only solution would be to either downgrade the version of .NET or to avoid using autocompletion for overrides all-together.

https://github.com/dotnet/vscode-csharp/issues/6076